# How to reverse the allowhtml tag which strips HTML from the module in Jomsocial

Tags: php, html, joomla, jomsocial

This is a beginner question, sorry! I'm dealing with a script that strips the HTML out of a module in Joomla using JomSocial. If there was some way to allow links and other HTML within the module, I could link to an admin-created page with the portfolio information, which is the ultimate goal.

Does anyone have any suggestions? I found the code that renders the short description modules in /groups.list.php, and it has a line that says:

```
   <div class="groupDescription"><?php echo ($config->get('allowhtml')) ? $group->description : $this->escape($group->description); ?></div>
```

I'm not very familiar with PHP, but doesn't the 'allowhtml' tag have something to do with this?

Thanks for any suggestions!

Answer (score 0):

`$config->get('allowhtml')` is a parameter which is probably coming from the component.

You will probably see in one of the module files the following code which will confirm that:

```
$config = JComponentHelper::getParams('com_componentname');
```

Therefore, go to the component in the Joomla backend, click the "Parameters" button in the top right, find the parameter and toggle between the options.

Comment: Checked that and it makes sense. However, there is an option within the Jomsocial component that allows html to be used in text areas. This is already checked to "on". The problem is that this particular "module" is stripping the html tags from the content. You can view the full HTML version of the content on another page. I'm wondering if this is a bug within the Jomsocial component or what.

Comment: could you upload the code from the module files to a file host so I can see it?

Comment: I'm not really sure which code I need to upload, honestly. There is a LOT of code here. If i remove the aformentioned code snippet, it removes the text completely, so i know this is the code being used to display the content in question.

Answer (score 0):

In jomosocial, menu item "configuration" , tab "layout" you have the an option "allow html" say yes, save and you have now html in common textareas like group descriptions.